# 2 ascii character counter in a file thats been given by the user

Tags: python

```
ascii_string= """!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"""

f=[]
file_name = input('Enter file name:')
with open(file_name) as file_char:

for character in (file_char):
    total_count= len(file_char)
    for file_char in (ascii_string):
        f.append(file_char)
for file_char in f:

    print("Total number of 2 ASCII characters: ", f)
```

so i want this to count how many pairs of ascii characters are in a file thats been given by the user any help?

Comment: What precisely is a pair here? Adjacent characters, or spread throughout the string? I.e., "aa" is a pair, but is "aba" also a pair of 'a's?

Comment: 2  adjacent characters

Comment: What about triplets and beyond: is "aaa" two pairs, only a triplet, or nothing at all? And "aaaa"? That could be zero, two or three pairs, depending on the definition.

Comment: well the "aaaa" would count as 2 pairs so it should be 2 adjacent characters and the triplets should count only as one even if it would be "abc" i dont want it to count "ab" and "bc"

Comment: So overlapping pairs are not allowed? (The "abc" example doesn't make sense here; it's about "aaa", which has overlapping pairs.)

Comment: no if its possible. cause it ll make it a lot slower and it ll give lots of results no needed

Comment: "No if its possible" is a tad unclear: I assumed you have hard constraints, but apparently you can relax them if programmatically it can't be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are searching for?

```py
ascii_string= """!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"""

counter = 0
file_name = input('Enter file name:')
with open(file_name) as f:
    data = f.read()
    for i in range(0,len(data)-1, 2):
        if data[i] in ascii_string and data[i+1] in ascii_string:
            counter+=1
print("Total number of 2 ASCII characters: ", str(counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall()` with a backreference:

```
>>> string = 'aaaab~~Q!!@@^^\\\\'
>>> re.findall(r'([!-~])\1', string)
['a', 'a', '~', '!', '@', '^', '\\']
```

If you want the search results to show the matching characters as pairs, simply wrap it in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [c+c for c in re.findall(r'([!-~])\1', string)]
['aa', 'aa', '~~', '!!', '@@', '^^', '\\\\']
```

To count them:

```
>>> len(re.findall(r'([!-~])\1', string))
7
```

(Note: `[!-~]` contains all printable ASCII characters (space excepted), like in your string. Alternative, there is `string.printable` in the `string` module, but that does contain the single space.)